# My input value's on dialog box form doesn't update

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, dialog

I'm looking for a solution to my problem. I couldn't find and answer, maybe because i don't know how to explain my problem in a search question..

I have a table with registries, and in everyone, i have and edit button, who open a bootstrap dialog, and show a form with the values (obtain by ajax) of that registry:

```
$("[href=edit]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $('#editModal').modal('show');

    $.post("tasas/get/",{id: id}, function(data){
        var form = $(data).find("div#editForm");
         $('.modal-body').html(form);
         $('#editModal').on("click","#acceptButton",function(){ 
            var concept = $('.modal-body [name=concept]').val();
            alert(concept);
            $('#frmEdit').submit();
        });
    });


 });
```

the $.post("tasas/get") return me a complete site, where i find specifically the div containing the form:

```
    <div id="editForm">
<form name="editRegistry" method="post" id="frmEdit" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="codigo" value="<?=$code?>">
    <label><span>Concept</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="concept" value="<?=$concept?>" />
    <label><span>Tipo</span></label>
    <select name="tipo">
        <option selected="selected" value="<?=$tipo?>"><?=$tipo?></option>
        <option value="$">$</option>
        <option value="%">%</option>
    </select>
    <label><span>Valor</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="valor" class="small" value="<?=$valor?>" />
</form>
</div>
```

Where the values are set by php results. Anyway, when i alert the concept that I have change on the form at the open dialog, it always show me the original value. Example:

The form is set with the concept value: "A". I change it to "B" on the form, and when I click the acceptButton, the alert show me "A" inside of "B", this makes that I couldn't edit the registry.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Why are you making an Ajax request to load a form to submit a form?

Comment: I make and ajax request to load the content of the values that i want to edit. What i want to do after that, is by ajax update those values on mysql. The submit will not be, will be a $.post!

Comment: I believe `$.post("tasas/get/")` is not enough; you target a directory, you should target a file like : `$.post("tasas/get/someFile.php")`

Comment: I use clean urls and always call index.php who hava a section and action controller, anyway thats works fine, i receive the form and the values have the data correctly, what i can't do, is to change the data on the input, and when click the accept button, obtain that new data on de .val(), i receive original data.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved it... What i was doing was alright. The thing was that i was duplicating code when i was doing the .html(form) part, as i have more than one dialog with the class .modal-body

So i replace:

$('.modal-body').html(form);

by

$('#editModal .modal-body').html(form);

and it works!

Regards Jeremy Thille and epascarello for trying to solved it!